# i am facing a problem in fetching image from firestore firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am try to add userimage of user on bottom navigation bar
i have created the variable name inituserimage and its getter
but inituserimage is not storeing the complete url of the image fetched from firestore as a link so it could be load.

**i am fetching the data in this file from firebase**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:straydogs/screens/LandingPage/landingUtils.dart';
import 'package:straydogs/services/Authentication.dart';

class FirebaseOperations with ChangeNotifier {
    late UploadTask imageUploadTask;
    late String initUserEmail, initUserName;
    late String initUserImage;
    String get getInitUserName => initUserName;
    String get getInitUserEmail => initUserEmail;
    String get getInitUserImage => initUserImage;

    Future uploadUserAvatar(BuildContext context) async {
      Reference imageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
          'userProfileAvatar/${Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).getUserAvatar.path}/${TimeOfDay.now()}');
      imageUploadTask = imageReference.putFile(
          Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).getUserAvatar);
      await imageUploadTask.whenComplete(() {
        print('Image Uploaded');
      });
      imageReference.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
        Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).userAvatarUrl =
            url.toString();
        print(
            'the user profile avatar url => ${Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).userAvatarUrl}');
        notifyListeners();
      });
    }

    Future createUserCollection(BuildContext context, dynamic data) async {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).getUserUid)
          .set(data);
    }

    Future initUserData(BuildContext context) {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).getUserUid)
          .get()
          .then((doc) {
        print('fetching user data');
        initUserName = doc['username'];
        initUserEmail = doc['useremail'];
        initUserImage = doc['userimage'];
        print(initUserName);
        print(initUserEmail);
        print(initUserImage);
        notifyListeners();
      });
    }
  }
```

**here i am using the image to be displayed on bottom navigation bar**

```
import 'package:custom_navigation_bar/custom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:straydogs/constants/Constantcolors.dart';
import 'package:straydogs/services/FirebaseOperations.dart';

class HomepageHelpers with ChangeNotifier {
  ConstantColors constantColors = ConstantColors();
  Widget bottomNavBar(BuildContext context, int index, PageController pageController) {
    return CustomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: index,
      bubbleCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
      scaleCurve: Curves.decelerate,
      selectedColor: constantColors.purple,
      unSelectedColor: constantColors.whiteColor,
      strokeColor: constantColors.purple,
      scaleFactor: 0.5,
      iconSize: 30.0,
      onTap: (val) {
        index = val;
        pageController.jumpToPage(val);
        notifyListeners();
      },
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff0e0021),
      items: [
        CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.home)),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.search)),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_rounded)),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 35.0,
          backgroundColor: constantColors.blueGreyColor,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(Provider.of<FirebaseOperations>(context,listen: false).getInitUserImage),
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPuHi.png)

[screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcdHb.png)

Answer (score 1):

in your FirebaseOperations you set the downloadURL to

```
Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).userAvatarUrl =
            url.toString();
```

but in the Widget you use:

```
backgroundImage: NetworkImage(Provider.of<FirebaseOperations>(context,listen: false).getInitUserImage),
```

So the solution is to use the right provider because you never set `initUserImage`
That says also the error `initUserImage` has not been initialized.

Comment: Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false).userAvatarUrl =
            url.toString();      is used in method to upload the image     -   but problem is in initUserData() function.

Comment: inituserimage variable is not storing the complete url of the image so the image is not fetched and not  displayed

Comment: initUserImage = doc['userimage']; problem is in this code even i try to print(doc['userimage']); it is printing half url as link and half as text

Comment: sorry but i can not help more when you not provide more information, because i can not see where you set the userimage url in the database

Comment: and the error says that you never set the variable initUserImage. Because it is marked as late you have to set it befor first use